# Javascript object manipulation

Tags: javascript, json

This is a follow up question to http://goo.gl/pmwjCV

I have a javascript ajax function that returns a JSON. I want to trigger different js events depending on the key value pair of the JSON but I am unable to access the JSON by key. So instead i converted the JSON to a javascript object and tried using IF but it's not working. Currently I keep getting error window even if JSON returns success. I have very little experience with javascript so please advice.

```
success: function (data) {

    var json = data,
        obj = JSON.parse(json);


    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('success')) //if data = {"result":"success"}
    {
        $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    } else // /if data = {"result":"error"}
    {
        $('form#loginForm').hide();
        $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");

    }
}
```

Comment: The `.hasOwnProperty()` function checks for property **names**, not property values. From the comment in your code you just want `if (obj.result == "success")`

Comment: Wow, now i feel stupid. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I think your check is wrong here, you are saying if your object has a property of 'success' but that is the value not the property.  Try something like this:

```
success: function (data) {

        var json = data,
            obj = JSON.parse(json);


        if (obj.result === 'success') //if data = {"result":"success"}
        {
            $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
        } else // /if data = {"result":"error"}
        {
            $('form#loginForm').hide();
            $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");

        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghkokgg7/

Comment: Yup i needed to use obj.result. Your code just got the error and success parts mixed. I posted the correct one below. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
  success: function (data) {

                var json = data,
                    obj = JSON.parse(json);


                if (obj.result === 'error') //if data = {"result":"success"}
                {
                    $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                } else // /if data = {"result":"error"}
                {
                    $('form#loginForm').hide();
                    $('div#loginResult').text("Login result: " + obj.result);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");

                }
            }
```